# ldexp or hex floats in C++/CLI

Tags: unit-testing, floating-point, c++-cli

I'm writing unit tests, using the Visual Studio unit testing framework, which expects me to use managed C++.

In my test, I want to test the accuracy and error recovery of a floating point helper function, so I'd like to load floating constants by specifying mantissa and exponent. In normal C++, I'd do this by using `ldexp`, however I cannot include `<math.h>`, or `<cmath>` from managed code.

Is there a way to load a (possibly denormalized) floating point constant?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I solved it by relaxing the build flags from `/clr:safe` to `/clr`.